# Create an envelope style graphic in Photoshop Elements

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-photoshop-elements

I need to create a sharper perfectly aligned graphic similar to this in Photoshop Elements. Any ideas on what tools I could use in Elements to create the shapes and keep the sizes in an even format with the sides and colour edge nice and clean?

[image]

Comment: i think elements is more of a photo editing package, to create something like you need you're going to want to use illustrator or photoshop.

Answer (score 0):

I agree, Illustrator will be so much better for this as it works in vector shapes rather than pixels and will give you consistently strong and clean lines where Photoshop will get fuzzy as you zoom.

With regards to making the shapes, just create some masks and you'll be just fine. If you need any more help let us know!

Chris